# Getting two sums from different tables with a joining table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to output the following:

```
ValueSum1 | ValueSum2
8 | 10
```

However I'm having a bit of difficulty. The Tables I have are:

**Table1**

```
ID  Value1  JoiningValue
1   3   1
2   2   2
3   3   2
```

**Table2**

```
ID  Value1  JoiningValue
1   5   3
2   2   3
3   2   3
4   1   2
```

**JoinTable**

```
ID
1
2
3
4
5
```

I need to be able to join the JoinTable to the query because I need to able to set a where condition specifically against values within the JoinTable.
I currently have:

```
SELECT SUM(Table1.Value1) 'ValueSum1',SUM(Table2.Value1) 'ValueSum2' From JoinTable
Left Join Table1
On JoinTable.ID = Table1.Joiningvalue
Left Join Table2
On JoinTable.ID = Table2.JoiningValue
```

However this is giving me the output of:

```
ValueSum1   ValueSum2
8   11
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aggregate the values *before* joining:

```
SELECT t1.ValueSum1, t2.ValueSum2
FROM JoinTable jt Left Join
     (SELECT Joiningvalue, SUM(Table1.Value1) as ValueSum1
      FROM Table1
      GROUP BY Joiningvalue
     ) t1
     On jt.ID = t1.Joiningvalue LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT Joiningvalue, SUM(Table2.Value1) as ValueSum2
      FROM Table2
      GROUP BY Joiningvalue
     ) t2
     On jt.ID = t2.JoiningValue;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great - did exactly what I wanted. Only thing I had to change was: SELECT SUM(t1.ValueSum1), SUM(t2.ValueSum2) to get the exact output I required.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1(ID  INT,
                    Value1  INT,
                    JoiningValue INT)
INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES
(1,3,1)
,(2,2,2)
,(3,3,2)

CREATE TABLE #Table2(ID INT,
                    value1 INT,
                    JoiningValue INT)

INSERT INTO #Table2 VALUES
(1,5,3)
,(2,2,3)
,(3,2,3)
,(4,1,2)


CREATE TABLE #Join(ID INT)
INSERT INTO #Join VALUES
(1)
,(2)
,(3)
,(4)
,(5)



SELECT  SUM(T1.Value1) ValueSum1,
        SUM(T2.value1) ValueSum2
FROM 
#Join J
INNER JOIN #Table1 T1
    ON J.ID = T1.ID
RIGHT JOIN #Table2 T2
    ON J.ID = T2.ID
```